# Asking about maximum expected height, based on random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

I Have a question like this:

The angle and velocity of throwing the ball follow normal distributions and are independent of each other, with mean 180° and 30m/s and standard deviations of 10° and 10 m/s, respectively.  Determine the maximum expected of throw.How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please state what you've tried, what you know, and where you're stuck. Otherwise it just looks like you're asking us to do your homework for you, and that's not what we do.

Comment: Someone else just asked the same question, but in a better way https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572915/determine-the-maximum-expected-height-of-johns-throw